# Cant get rid of error message when running ant-launcher from jre-java

Tags: java, ant

Running ant from java with the following command always result in a warning.

```
/opt/java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java -jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar build.xml
```

Warning:

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /opt/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/tools.jar

I am fully aware that ant is launched with JRE instead of JDK, I was wondering if it is possible to get rid of/suppress this error message, because it feeds unecessary information into logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

- you might want to provide an additional tools.jar in your class path; maybe that is good enough to make ant happy
- you ignore the warning; or you built a simple log-file-cleanup utility that removes these lines

What I mean is: you are using a tool in a way that the tool doesn't like. Those messages are symptom. If at all, you ignore symptoms; you don't start fighting them. See [here](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/tools-jar-not-found-td5715788.html) for example:

> Ant is a build tool. For some tasks (for example javac, javadoc) the tools from the Java *Development* Kit are **required**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to get rid of the problem at the root if possible, but I guess I'm using it in an unintended way so i will mend the problem by filtering the logs instead.